# readline: How do I call a vi command in emacs mode?

Tags: bash, readline

`bind -pm vi` says:

> ```
> ",": vi-char-search
> ";": vi-char-search
> "F": vi-char-search
> "T": vi-char-search
> "f": vi-char-search
> "t": vi-char-search
> ```

So, `vi-char-search` performs different functions depending on how it is called.

In `emacs` mode, if I want to map `Control-[` to the `t` version `Control-]` to the `f` version, how can I do that?

Comment: Consider using zsh. Its line editor is a lot more configurable than bash's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution:

```
"f": character-search
"F": character-search-backward
```